# Looking for an employee scheduling module

Tags: datetime

Using D7, I need to be able to schedule call center staff. Is there any "employee scheduling" module out there?

If not, are there a combination of modules I can use to create such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I created a shift scheduler module about a year ago.

Documentation and Releases: http://code.google.com/p/drupal-shift-scheduler/

Video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pPHtoE2ivg

Development: http://drupal.org/sandbox/mcstrother/1075572

I'm no longer actively developing it, but I believe both the 6 and 7 versions are actively in use on at least one production site each with no new bugs reported.